# Junit Error after adding spring boot actuator dependency in project

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, dependencies, spring-boot-actuator

I have a project which works alright but as soon as I add Spring boot actuator dependency in the pom.xml I get the following error when I build the project ->

```
Error:java: cannot access org.junit.platform.commons.annotation.Testable
  class file for org.junit.platform.commons.annotation.Testable not found
  Consult the following stack trace for details.
  com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.junit.platform.commons.annotation.Testable not found
```

The dependency that I have added is ->

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have tried looking for the fix online but haven't found any success.

Comment: Check your resolved dependency and whether you have more than one JUnit version imported.

Comment: My project does have multiple junit versions for different modules. Can you please explain how that might cause this issue when i add actuator dependency in one of the modules?

Comment: Most likely it has nothing to do with actuator dependency, multiple version can cause problem any time it depends how the class is being loaded sometimes from one or other. Better you remove the duplicate copy or check with mvn dependency:tree from where you are getting those.